# Can i compile in memory source code to executable with clang?

Tags: clang

reading this link :http://fdiv.net/2012/08/15/compiling-code-clang-api
i see i can load c/c++ file and compile it just fine to executable..
but i did't found any info if i have some kind of source code in c/c++
that my application generating or other way ..
in short can i pass the stage where i load the c file , and just build my own logic to compile to executable ?

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can. And there is already a project for that purpose
Dig its source codes as your wish :)
[Cling](http://root.cern.ch/drupal/content/cling)

```
What is Cling

Cling is an interactive C++ interpreter, built on the top of   
LLVM and Clang libraries. Its advantages over the standard  
interpreters are that it has command line prompt and uses  
just-in-time (JIT) compiler for compilation. Many of the developers  
(e.g. Mono in their project called CSharpRepl) of such kind 
of software applications name them interactive compilers.

One of Cling's main goals is to provide contemporary, high-performance  
alternative of the current C++ interpreter in the ROOT project -  
CINT. The backward-compatibility with CINT is major priority during  
the development.
```

Comment: befor i start reading , can it compile from memory source ? 
without loading file from disk ? do i still need external linker ?

Comment: No, you don't need neither loading nor a external linker. it's interpreter, a little bit like python. You could download and try it.

Comment: i will , it will be able to give me single exe in the end ?